# Creating a data type list Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I've done a personal list in Haskell like this:  (2,(1,1),3) -> List [Num 2, List [Num 1, Num 1], List [Num 3]].

This is how I made it:

```
data SList a = Num a | List [SList a] deriving Show
emptySList :: SList a
emptySList = (List [])

consElem :: a -> SList a -> SList a
consElem x (List y) = (List ((Num x) : y))

consList :: SList a -> SList a -> SList a
consList a b = (List [a,b])
```

I manage to form this list (List [Num 2, List [Num 1, Num 1], List [Num 3]]) using consElem and consList like this:

```
consElem 2 $ consList (consElem 1 $ consElem 1 emptySList) $ consElem 3 emptySList
```

I wonder how can I transform a SList in a normal list. For example if I have this SList: `List [Num 2, List [Num 1, Num 1], List [Num 3]]` it should become `[2,1,1,3]`.

My attempt:

```
atomToNormal x
    | null x = []
    | otherwise = slistToList (head x) ++ atomToNormal (tail x)
slistToList :: SList a -> [a]
slistToList (List x) = atomToNormal x
slistToList (Num x) = [x]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? (Your `SList` is a tree type, so any tree traversal should work.)

Comment: This is what I have by now :
`onebyone (Num x) = x`

`atomToNormal x 
 | null x = []
 | otherwise = (onebyone $ head x) : atomToNormal (tail x)` 


`slistToList (List x) = atomToNormal x`

Comment: That looks like it would almost work. You just have to change `(onebyone $ head x) :` to `slistToList (head x) ++` (and handle the `Num` case in `slistToList`).

Comment: I change the code as you said. But it doesn't work. It bring me this error:
`No instance for (Num (SList [t0]))`

Comment: Try adding a type signature to `slistToList`. What should its type be?

Comment: It should be `SList a -> [a]` because this function should give me a normal list.

Comment: So put `slistToList :: SList a -> [a]` in your code and see if you get a better error message. :-)

Answer (score 1):

GHC can actually write this function for you:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
import Data.Foldable as Foldable

data SList a = Num a | List [SList a]
  deriving (Show, Foldable)

slistToList :: SList a -> [a]
slistToList = Foldable.toList
```

If you want to do it yourself – I don't see quite what `atomToNormal` is supposed to do, you don't need it. Just deconstruct the tree-branch list<sup>†</sup> head-first right in `slistToList`:

```
slistToList :: SList a -> [a]
slistToList (Num x) = _
slistToList (List []) = _
slistToList (List (l:ls)) = _
```

Now fill in the gaps. GHC (>=7.10) can help you a lot there too: just try compiling as-is with the underscore-gaps, and it will tell you

```
/tmp/wtmpf-file17703.hs:8:23:
    Found hole ‘_’ with type: [a]
    Where: ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for slistToList :: SList a -> [a]
               at /tmp/wtmpf-file17703.hs:7:16
    Relevant bindings include
      x :: a (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file17703.hs:8:18)
      slistToList :: SList a -> [a]
        (bound at /tmp/wtmpf-file17703.hs:8:1)
    In the expression: _
    In an equation for ‘slistToList’: slistToList (Num x) = _
```

So the first gap needs to have type `[a]`, and the only value you have is `x::a`. Well, you can wrap that in a singleton list

```
slistToList (Num x) = [x]
```

Proceed in the same fashion with the other clauses. As a rule of thumb, if you just somehow include all of the “relevant bindings” (often, there's exactly one way to do this), then your implementation will probably be right.

Of course, this only works when you first write out the type signature... which *should always be the first thing you do anyway*!

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Your type really should be called something tree-ish, not `SList`!</sub>

Comment: This type is actually `Free [] a`, and I would use it as such. Something called `Tree a` is relatively ambiguous about its meaning, while `Free [] a` is very standard. Best to use a type synonym or newtype + GND for instances.

Comment: @Lazersmoke well, it is also [the standard `Tree` type from the `containers` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Tree.html). I would use it by that name. Sure, like many other types you can also express it through `Free`, but what's the point? If you'd go this route consequently, you'd actually have to write `Free (Free (Free (Const ())))`. This is silly.

Comment: @leftaroundabout `Tree` is `Cofree []`. `SList Char` can be `List [List [Num 'a']]`, `Free [] Char` can be `Free [Free [Pure 'a']]`, `Cofree`/`Tree` can't do this.

Comment: Alright, true. In particular you can have (even arbitrarily deep) _empty_ structures with `Free []`, whereas `Tree` always has at least one value. Actually rather a forest than a tree thus.